# undefined method `user_name' for nil:NilClass when adding comments form for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

everything was working until I add the form_for  for creating comments and I get this error undefined method `user_name' for nil:NilClass...

I searching for hours for solution but in vain..
here is my posts views index file  with the form I added for creating the comments:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= render 'form' %>
            <div id="posts" class="transitions-enabled">
                <% @posts.each do |post| %>
                    <div class="box box-1 panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <%= link_to image_tag(post.user.avatar.url, size: "50x50", class: "img-circle"), profile_path(post.user.user_name) %>
                            <ul class="posts-shows">
                            <li><strong><%= link_to post.user.user_name, profile_path(post.user.user_name)  %></strong></li>
                            <li><small><%= link_to "#{time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)} ago", post_path(post), class: "time-link" %> </small></li>
                        </ul>
                            <p class="disc-posts"><%= post.description %></p>
                            <%= link_to image_tag(post.image.url(:large), class: "img-responsive img-in" ) %><br/>
                            <% if post.user == current_user %>
                                <div><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %> | <%= link_to "delete", post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %> </div>
                            <% else %>                          
                                <div><%= link_to "Repost", repost_post_path(post), method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} if user_signed_in? %></div>                 
                            <% end %>
                        </div>


                        <%= form_for([post, post.comments.build]) do |f| %> 
                            <p>
                            <%= f.label :content %><br> 
                            <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control"  %>
                            </p> 

                            <p> 
                            <%= f.submit %> 
                            </p> 

                        <% end %>

                        <% if post.comments.present? %>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
                                    <%= link_to image_tag(post.user.avatar.url, size: "30x30", class: "img-circle"), profile_path(comment.user.user_name) %>
                                    <%= link_to comment.user.user_name, profile_path(comment.user.user_name), class: "username-size" %>
                                    <%= comment.content %>
                                    <% if comment.user == current_user %>
                                        <%= link_to "delete", post_comment_path(post, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
                                    <% end %>
                                <% end %>
                            </div>
                        <% end %>


                    </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the form_for alone:

```
<%= form_for([post, post.comments.build]) do |f| %> 
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %><br> 
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control"  %>
   </p> 

   <p> 
     <%= f.submit %> 
   </p> 

 <% end %>
```

and here is my comment, user and post model that shows the associations :

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

.........................

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :description
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

......................

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :user_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 16 } 
end
```

and my comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post

  def index
    @comments = @post.comment.all
  end

  def new
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comments_params)
  end

  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comments_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Check the comment form"
      render root_path
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

    @comment.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Comment deleted :("
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

my schema:

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "original_post_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
```

Comment: did you get solution.??

Comment: seems like few comments  don't have user_id in this line <%= link_to comment.user.user_name, profile_path(comment.user.user_name), class: "username-size" %>

Comment: check for comment.user_id.present? and then create a link_to user_name

Comment: @Deepak oooo it is working now, first I want to thank you a lot...It is working....but what was the problem...As I deleted all the comments first but the problem did not get solved until you come...what do you think?

Comment: I think you created few comments prior to having association between user and comment. later on when you added association between them the older comment's user_id will be nil. so when u try to access user_name for those comments it will show that error

Comment: Yes, as @pavan said you must have created few comments without user_id either from console or before applying validations

Comment: @sam0101 I will add an answer then

Comment: i dont remember If I did that or not but anyway thank you again...

Answer (score 1):

seems like few comments don't have user_id in this line

```
<%= link_to comment.user.user_name, profile_path(comment.user.user_name), class: "username-size" %>
```

Try destroying the comments with `user_id` having `nil` value

```
Comment.destroy_all(user_id: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your post table have `user_id` or others `foreign key` ?

You can use :

`belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'` at `post.rb` model

And :

`has_many :posts, :foreign_key => 'user_id'` at `user.rb`

Comment: Hi yes i have user_id in post table...I updated my question and add the shcema of the posts and comments table

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Rails myself, but I've worked through similar errors a dozen times. This bit appears to be a problem:

```
profile_path(post.user.user_name)
```

Earlier in the same line of code, you use:

```
link_to post.user.user_name
```

but that part seems okay, because it's just the displayed text.

In the actual link, I don't think you should include the user_name. Try simply using "post.user" instead.

Comment: Did you get them all? You've got that same syntax in four different lines from that first block that you posted.

Comment: now I get that error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :user_name=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_name]"....so I think I have to add the .user_name there ...because that what I defined in profile routes (profile GET    /:user_name) so in my case the user_name is necessary and it seems that it is not the root of the problem in my case